# Take data from one list to another

Tags: angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two tables in my HTML. I want to take data from one list and pass it to another. I can't do the same ng-repeat call because on the second table I have one individual customer and I just want to display his ID. On the first table, I have all the customers.

```
<table border="1" id="userTable">
    <tr>
        <b>#</b>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in userList" ng-click="viewUserDiv()">
        <td ng-model="id">{{user.id}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div ng-show="userDiv">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <b>#</b>
    </tr>
        <td ng-model="id">{{id}}</td>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want to show userDiv when they click the first row? Pass the user in your ng-click function `ng-click="viewUserDiv(user)"` and in that function setup the data for the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border="1" id="userTable">
    <tr>
        <b>#</b>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in userList" ng-click="viewUserDiv(user)">
        <td ng-model="id">{{user.id}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>


$scope.viewUserDiv = function(user) {
    if (user) {
        $scope.userDiv = true;
        $scope.userDivUser = user;
    }
}

<div ng-show="userDiv">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <b>#</>
        </tr>
            <td ng-model="userDivUser">{{userDivUser.id}}</td>
    </table>
<div>
```

Comment: you could even get rid of `$scope.userDiv = true` and change the `ng-show` to `ng-show="userDivUser"`